# Two Images on a JButton with Text at bottom

Tags: java, image, user-interface, jbutton, settext

I've looked for this quite a bit and I haven't found it, sorry if this was answered before but I don't think it has been. I am making a client-sided Shop for a game, I have the interface, the images, everything, when I have the text set in the middle it shows perfectly fine.

http://prntscr.com/4ffdds

But if I set the text to display at the bottom, it does this: http://prntscr.com/4ffdn9
I am using:

```
shopButton.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
shopButton.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
```

to set the text which is confusing me, but that's not the main problem. I also need to have an image in the boxes on the screen, here is the function I am using to create the buttons:

```
public void createBuyButton(final JButton shopButton, JLabel image, BufferedImage sprite, int x, int y, int width, int height, int i){
        shopButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(cropImage(sprite, button.getButtonRect("BUYBUTTON"))));
        shopButton.setRolloverIcon(new ImageIcon(cropImage(sprite, button.getButtonRect("BUYBUTTON_OVERLAY"))));
        shopButton.setText(shopItems.getNameOfItems()[i]);
        shopButton.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        shopButton.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
        shopButton.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        image.add(shopButton);
    return;
}
```

I am using a for loop to loop through all the buttons I have. How would I add another image over the background image so it shows when I'm not hovering over it and when I am hovering over it? Tell me if you need more information, I'll reply as soon as I see it.

Answer (score 0):

```
shopButton.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
```

Don't use setBounds(...). I would guess your size is incorrect so the text is being truncated.

Let the layout manager of the component calculate the size. By default a JLabel doesn't have a layout manager so if you want to add a button to a label then try the following:

```
image.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
image.add( shopButton );
```

Although I must admit I don't understand why you are adding a button to a label?

Comment: Thanks, i'll give this a try, and i am adding a button to a jlabel because it creates an interface of purely pictures ^^ atleast that's how i've been doing it. I don't think the size is wrong since i am taking it directly from the rectangle i used to crop the image out ^^

Comment: @Lygophobia The button by default also has a margin, meaning that the button will (have to) be larger than the image that you place into the `ImageIcon`. (You could set the margin insets to (0,0,0,0), but I also don't recommend using setBounds manually...)